# How to see what factor variables are coded as in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a column that has values of Yes and No and they are coded in an unconventional 2 or 3.  I would guess that NO is the lower number,2, and that YES is the larger number 3, but I cannot be sure.

Is there a way to discover which is coded as which?

```
str(df$col)
```

shows me

```
Factor w/2 levels 'no','yes': 3,2,3,2,3, etc and I can't tell from this.
```

viewing the actual file in R shows yes and no, not numbers.

Is there a command that lets me decode?

Comment: What does `dput(head(df$col))` return? It's odd that's it's not 1/2. rather than 2/3.

Comment: I'm really surprised that a factor with 2 levels has a 3 in it... that should produce `NA`

Comment: Are there NAs in `df$col`? Check `sum(is.na(df$col))`

Answer (score 1):

I believe neither is the case - "no" is 1, "yes" is 2, and 3 is NA:

```
> col = structure(c(3, 2, 3, 2, 3), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")
> col
[1] <NA> yes  <NA> yes  <NA>
Levels: no yes
> str(col)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "no","yes": 3 2 3 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`levels(df$col)` should do what you need, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Could create some silly utility function as follows

```
factfun <- function(x){
  unique(data.frame(Level = as.character(x), Encoding = as.numeric(x)))
}
```

Usage

```
factfun(df$col)
```

---

Testing on @SenorsO data

```
col = structure(c(3, 2, 3, 2, 3), .Label = c("no", "yes"), class = "factor")
factfun(col)
##   Level Encoding
## 1  <NA>        3
## 2   yes        2
```